# How do I get a line of a text file with the line number in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, string, echo, line-numbers

I have tried this, but I don't know why it doesn't work:

```
<?php
$roomid = $_GET["roomid"];
$file = fopen('Rooms//testid.txt','a+');
$lines = file('Rooms//testid.txt'); 
$search = $roomid;
$line_number = false;

while (list($key, $line) = each($lines) and !$line_number) {
  $line_number = (strpos($line, $search) !== FALSE) ? $key + 1 : $line_number;
}
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$lines[$line_number]');</script>";
?>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Find which line `$search` appears in?

Comment: @AlexHowansky If I only put the line number in the alert box it works fine, and I see the right line number in the alert box , but if I put `$lines[$line_number]` in the alert box I don't get an alert box at all.

Comment: I think more explanation is required as to what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The loop is overly complicated. You don't need the line number, just the line. You can use a boolean variable to determine if the search string was found, and a `break` statement to end the loop instead of the complex `while` condition.

Also, your index was off by 1 because you assigned `$key + 1` to `$line_number`.

```
$found = false;
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (strpos($line, $search) !== FALSE) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if ($found) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$line');</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$roomid not found');</script>";
}
```

Comment: I've added a second alert if it's not found, is that showing?

Comment: Thanks, I ran into an enter issue (\n), that's probably the issue too of my previous code, but now I have the line could you tell me how to remove it?

Comment: Use the `array_splice()` function to remove an element from an array.